# How to enable USB connection mode on Samsung Galaxy Fit?

Tags: usb-connection-mode

How to enable USB connection mode in Samsung Galaxy Fit mobile?

When I connect my mobile to laptop via a data cable, I am unable to transfer data between PC-mobile and mobile-PC.

The option "USB settings" under Settings tab is missing in my mobile. I have enabled USB Debugging mode under Applications tab in my mobile.

I tried all the viable options but still am unable to select the mode as Charge mode/USB mode etc on my mobile.

What could I have missed?

Answer (score -2):

Hi try clicking Notification Scroll down to find 'USB Connected' like option... press go navigate